# How to create an index exemption on Firestore subdocuments?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We have a database structured as follows:

- Collection `foo`

  - Documents

    - Collection `bar`

      - Documents with many fields (approaching the 1 MB limit)

Trying to write a document to the `bar` collection containing 34571 fields, I get (from the Go API):

> rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = too many builtin index entries for entity

OK, fine, [it seems](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_best_practices) I need to add an exemption:

> Large array or map fields
>
> Large array or map fields can approach the limit of 20,000 index entries per document. If you are not querying based on a large array or map field, you should exempt it from indexing.

**But how?** The console only lets me set a single collection name and a single field path, and slashes aren't accepted:

[image: "Add exemption" dialog]

I tried other combinations, but `/` isn't accepted in either the `Collection ID` or the `Field path`, and using `.`, while not clearly forbidden, results in a generic error when trying to save the exemption. I'm also not sure if `*` is allowed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**: You can now [use the `*` wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview#single-field_index_exemptions) to add collection-level index exemptions on all fields in a collection group

**Previous**:
Index exemptions are based on collection ID and not collection path. In this case, you can enter `bar` as the collection ID. This also means the exemption applies to all collections with ID `bar`, regardless of hierarchy.

As for the fields, you can specify only a single field path per exemption. The "*" all-selector is not supported. There is a [limit of 200 index exemptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_limits) so you wouldn't be able to exempt all 34571 fields. If possible, I suggest moving your fields into a map. Then you could disable indexing on the map field.

Comment: This sounds like a severe limitation :(

Comment: Haven't it changed for '*'? https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview?&_ga=2.268962805.-500620222.1709465273#single-field_index_exemptions "Use the * field path value to add collection-level index exemptions on all fields in a collection group"