# How to turn off automatic indexes in firestore for subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't want to have automatic indexes created by firestore because I need to remove and add every five minutes 50-100 documents (each doc has +/-60 fields) to my subcollection. This causes of big volume for "Cloud Firestore Index Write Ops" (300k / day for only one user) and Cloud Storage. I don't need to sort, filtering that documents so I suppose I can turn off automatic indexes, right?

I know that I can add exemptions for fields, but I don't know how can I use it for documents in subcollections. What should I pass in Collection ID and Field path if the path for documents is like:

```
mainCollectionName/{id}/subcollectionName/{document=**}
```

and when should I select a collection checkbox and when collection group checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to disable indexes or create exemptions for documents to be indexed. As clarified in this similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909646/how-to-create-an-index-exemption-on-firestore-subdocuments), this cannot be achieved and there is even a limit of 200 exemptions of fields that can be done - you can check the limits [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_limits).

For your case, indeed, you would have to exempt the fields individually and besides that, to create the exemption, to set the collection you use its `id` and not the path. So, you would only need to set in the `Collection ID` field the `subcollectionName` and then the field to be exempted.

In addition to this, feel free to raise a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0), so they can check about implementing an exemption of documents in the future.

Comment: Thx for help. As can I see, it's a good idea to use a map. I need to use it, make sense.